# How to avoid selecting a cell address when using the arrow keys while editing a cell

Tags: google-sheets

Sometimes, while editing the contents of a cell, using the arrow keys will not move the cursor but instead inserts the address to an adjacent cell.

Here is an example of this problem with a screenshot: I go into an empty cell and enter `=SUMIF(` and then decide I want to use a normal `SUM` instead of a `SUMIF` so I hit the left arrow key once to move the cursor back, but this enters the address of the cell to the left.
[image: screenshot of arrow key setting a cell address]

It doesn't always happen, so I wonder if there are conditions which cause it to occur which can be avoided. Is there a meta key which ensure the arrows can be used for navigation? Or can this functionality be disabled entirely?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

## Short answer

Google Sheets doesn't have [meta-keys](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Meta_key) that disable cell navigation and referencing during the edition of a formula and this behaviour can't be disabled.

## Workarounds

1. Add `)` before pressing the left arrow key.
   i.e. if you write `=SUMIF(`, press <kbd>)</kbd> so you have `=SUMIF()`. Now press the left arrow key.
2. Press <kbd>Backspace</kbd> instead of the left arrow key.

**References**
[Keyboard shortcuts for Google Sheets - Docs editors Help](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/181110?hl=en)

Answer (score 0):

Since having asked this question a few years ago (and the usability issue yet to be resolved), I've concluded the best way to disable this annoying behavior is to exclude the `=` prefix until you've finished typing your formula. Without the `=`, a cell is considered "text only", and Google Sheets will not apply any "help" while editing (no annoying auto-cell-reference behavior, but also no useful function usage tips, nor syntax or parenthesis highlighting). It works really well (for me) to enter a formula in plain text, without interruption, then hit `⌘`+`←` or `ctrl`+`a` (on macOS) to move to the beginning and then type the `=`.